# How to specify both an upper and lower limit for a pod in the Podfile

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods

An [issue](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1961) was generating warning in my Xcode project. This was resolved in version 2.2.3 (a patch version change i.e. the problem is there in 2.2.2).

Previously my Podfile used:

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
```

This matched all versions 2.0+ but limited the match to less than 3.0 i.e. a major version change was ignored.

Since the change I require is important (I don't want warnings lingering when I code) and is available only in versions 2.2.3+ I want a specification for my pod like

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '>= 2.2.3 & < 3.0'
```

Please note that I still don't want a major version bump to screw everything up, which is possible if I only use:

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '>= 2.2.3'
```

because this will match 3.0 too..

The issue is that [Cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org/) doesn't allow this and rejects it in parsing itself with error:

```
ArgumentError - Illformed requirement `">= 2.2.3 & < 3.0"`
```

Reference:

- [Podfile Syntax](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod)

As far as I could traceback, when parsing the Podfile, the version specification is matched with the regular expression :

```
quoted_operators = OPS.keys.map { |k| Regexp.quote k }.join '|'
PATTERN = /\A\s*(#{quoted_operators})?\s*(#{Version::VERSION_PATTERN})\s*\z/
```

File : cocoapods-core-0.32.1/lib/cocoapods-core/requirement.rb https://github.com/CocoaPods/Core/blob/master/lib/cocoapods-core/requirement.rb

This pattern only allows for one specification..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should specify each version requirement separately, e.g. `pod 'AFNetworking', '>= 2.2.3', '< 3.0'`.

Which is what is meant by “A list of version requirements can be specified for even more fine grained control.” in the Podfile syntax guide.

Comment: Thanks! Can I put the blame on me not being from "ruby world"? :grin: